# XML child values coming in strung together as on long string

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Items>
 <textBoxCenterName>Denver Dispatch</textBoxCenterName>
 <textBoxContactFirstName>Eric</textBoxContactFirstName>

 <servicedUnits>
   <unit>CO-ADX (Adams County)</unit>
   <unit>CO-AFQ (Air Force Academy)</unit>
   <unit>CO-ALDS (CSFS-Alamosa District)</unit>
   <unit>CO-ALX (Alamosa County)</unit>
</servicedUnits>

</Items>
```

I am using the following code to pull in the `servicedUnits` as listBox items:

```
XElement element = XElement.Load("FCAT-Settings.xml");
foreach (XElement item in element.Elements("servicedUnits"))
    listBoxServicedUnits.Items.Add(item.Value);
```

The items are coming in as one long string concatenated, like so:

```
CO-ADX (Adams County)CO-AFQ (Air Force Academy)CO-ALDS (CSFS-Alamosa District)CO-ALX (Alamosa County)
```

So I end up with one item in the listbox with all these `servicedUnits` strung together.

How can I solve this? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Simply each item in a separate line?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the selection. `element.Elements("servicedUnits")` returns the list of `servicedUnits` elements (Only 1 in the XML), and what you wanted is the list of elements INSIDE that element, for example `element.Elements("servicedUnits").Elements()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try getting child nodes:

```
    foreach (XElement item in element.Elements("servicedUnits").Elements())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to iterate over a single element (`servicedUnits`) instead of iterating over the collection of `unit` elements that you intend to. The output of your current implementation is simply giving you the total `Value` of your `servicedUnits` element, which is the value of each of its child elements.

To get what you seemingly intend to have, you need to iterate over your `unit` elements, like this:

```
foreach(XElement item in element.Element("servicedUnits").Elements("unit"))
{
    //add to listbox, whatever
}
```

This sample implementation assumes you only have a single `servicedUnits` element, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is by using the `Descendents` method on an `XDocument`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"FCAT-Settings.xml");
var units = xdoc
    .Descendants("servicedUnits")
    .SelectMany(u => u.Descendants("unit").Select(x => x.Value));
foreach (var unit in units)
    listBoxServicedUnits.Items.Add(unit);
```

This also ensures you will only get the values for the "unit" nodes.